# sql lowest running balance in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been trying for days to solve this problem to no solution.
I want to get the lowest running balance in a group.
Here is a sample data

[image]

The running balance is imaginary and is not part of the table.
the running balance is also computed dynamically.

the problem is I want to get the lowest running balance in a Specific month (January)
so the output should be 150 for memberid 10001 and 175 for memberid 10002  as highlighted in the image.
my desired out put should be

memberid | balance

10001 | 150

10002 | 175

Is that possible using sql query only?

PS. Using c# to compute lowest running balance is very slow since I have more than 600,000 records in my table.

I've updated the question.

Comment: Define **SLOWEST RUNNING BALANCE**

Comment: lowest balance computation between deposit and withdrawal as a running balance or do you have a better term?

Comment: @Mandz Do you need the query in `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: ok i'll remove it, im using sql server

Comment: Based on what you told us, taking the absolute `MIN` should suffice.  Can you describe what constitutes a group here?

Comment: @Mandz So basically the current running balance for a given row, is the sum of all  deposits - withdrawals from the *preceding* rows?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it looks like the `RunningBalance` column does not exist yet. It was computed dynamically.

Comment: yes the running balance is computed dynamically. It will be grouped by memberid, and by month.

Comment: Do you want  the lowest running balance of the every member's savings Id or only the lowest running balance?

Comment: i want the lowest running balance in memberid per month or in a specifiic month

Comment: Do you want to calculate this for a single user or for all users?

Comment: i want to calculate this for all the user. Sorry if I have a trouble explaining the problem. ^_^

Comment: I've prepared the solution in `MySQL` and just identified that you are using `SQL-SERVER` :(

Comment: the important is the idea on how to implement it. because currently i have no idea how to implement it. hopefully it can be translated to sql server. It was my bad in the first place to put mysql in my tag sorry :(

Comment: @1000111 If it works in MySQL, you should be able to port it over to SQL Server without too much trouble I would imagine.

Comment: I don't know `SQL-SERVER` syntax. If you are able to convert it to `SQL-SERVER` syntax then I can post.

Comment: sure I will not downvote it. just indicate in the post that the solution is in mysql. I will try to port it in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by Mihir Shah gave me the idea how solve my problem.
His answer takes to much time to process making it as slow as my computation on my c# program because his code loops on every record.

Here is my answer to get the minimum lowest value in a specific group (specific month) with a running value or running total without sacrificing a lot of performance.

```
with IniMonth1 as 
(
select a.memberid, a.iniDeposit, a.iniWithdrawal, 
(cast(a.iniDeposit as decimal(10,2)) - cast(a.iniWithdrawal as decimal(10,2))) as RunningTotal
from
(
    select b.memberid, sum(b.depositamt) as iniDeposit, sum(b.withdrawalamt) as iniWithdrawal
    from savings b
    where trdate < '01/01/2016'
    group by b.memberid 
) a /*gets all the memberid, sum of deposit amount and withdrawal amt from the beginning of the savings before the specific month */
where cast(a.iniDeposit as decimal(10,2)) - cast(a.iniWithdrawal as decimal(10,2))  > 0 /*filters zero savings */
)
```

[image]

```
,DetailMonth1 as 
(
select a.memberid, a.depositamt,a.withdrawalamt, 
(cast(a.depositamt as decimal(10,2)) - cast(a.withdrawalamt as decimal(10,2))) as totalBal, 
    Row_Number() Over(Partition By a.memberid Order By a.trdate Asc) RowID
from savings a
where
a.trdate >= '01/01/2016'
and 
a.trdate <= '01/31/2016'
and (a.depositamt<>0 or a.withdrawalamt<>0)
) /* gets all record within the specific month and gives a no of row as an id for the running value in the next procedure*/
```

[image]

```
,ComputedDetailMonth1 as 
(   
select a.memberid, min(a.runningbalance) as MinRunningBal
from
(
    select a.rowid, a.memberid, a.totalbal, 
    (
        sum(b.totalbal) + 
        (case 
        when c.runningtotal is null then 0
        else c.runningtotal
        end)
    )as runningbalance , c.runningtotal as oldbalance
    from DetailMonth1 a
    inner join DetailMonth1 b
        on  b.rowid<=a.rowid
        and a.memberid=b.memberid
    left join IniMonth1 c
    on a.memberid=c.memberid
    group by a.rowid,a.memberid,a.totalbal,c.runningtotal
) a

group by a.memberid
) /* the loop is only for the records of the specific month only making it much faster */  
/* this gets the running balance of specific month ONLY and ADD the sum total of IniMonth1 using join to get the running balance from the beginning of savings to the specific month */
/* I then get the minimum of the output using the min function*/
```

[image]
[image]

```
, OldBalanceWithNoNewSavingsMonth1 as
(
select a.memberid,a.RunningTotal
from 
IniMonth1 a
left join 
DetailMonth1 b
on a.memberid = b.memberid
where b.totalbal is null
)/*this gets all the savings that is not zero and has no transaction in the specific month making and this will become the default value as the lowest value if the member has no transaction in the specific month. */
```

[image]

```
,finalComputedMonth1 as
(
select a.memberid,a.runningTotal as MinRunTotal from OldBalanceWithNoNewSavingsMonth1 a
union 
select b.memberid,b.MinRunningBal from ComputedDetailMonth1 b
)/*the record with minimum running total with clients that has a transaction  in the specific month Unions with the members with no current transaction in the specific month*/

 select * from finalComputedMonth1 order by memberid /* display the final output */
```

[image]

I have more than 600k savings record on my savings table

Surprisingly the performance of this code is very efficient.

It takes almost 2hr using my c# program to manually compute every record of all the members.

This code makes only 2 secs and at most 9 secs just to compute everything.
i Just display to c# for another 2secs.

The output of this code was tested and compared with my computation using my c# program.

Answer (score 0):

May be below one is help you

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @CashFlow Table
(
     savingsid      Varchar(50)
    ,memberid       Int
    ,trdate         Date
    ,deposit        Decimal(18,2)
    ,withdrawal     Decimal(18,2)
)

Insert Into @CashFlow(savingsid,memberid,trdate,deposit,withdrawal) Values
 ('10001-0002',10001,'01/01/2015',1000,0)
,('10001-0003',10001,'01/07/2015',25,0)
,('10001-0004',10001,'01/13/2015',25,0)
,('10001-0005',10001,'01/19/2015',0,900)
,('10001-0006',10001,'01/25/2015',25,0)
,('10001-0007',10001,'01/31/2015',25,0)
,('10001-0008',10001,'02/06/2015',25,0)
,('10001-0009',10001,'02/12/2015',25,0)
,('10001-0010',10001,'02/18/2015',0,200)
,('10002-0001',10002,'01/01/2015',500,0)
,('10002-0002',10002,'01/07/2015',25,0)
,('10002-0003',10002,'01/13/2015',0,200)
,('10002-0004',10002,'01/19/2015',25,0)
,('10002-0005',10002,'01/25/2015',25,0)
,('10002-0006',10002,'01/31/2015',0,200)
,('10002-0007',10002,'02/06/2015',25,0)
,('10002-0008',10002,'02/12/2015',25,0)
,('10002-0009',10002,'02/12/2015',0,200)

;With TrialBalance As
(
    Select   Row_Number() Over(Partition By cf.memberid Order By cf.trdate Asc) RowNum
            ,cf.memberid
            ,cf.deposit
            ,cf.withdrawal
            ,cf.trdate
    From    @CashFlow As cf
)
,RunningBalance As
(
    Select   tb.RowNum
            ,tb.memberid
            ,tb.deposit
            ,tb.withdrawal
            ,tb.trdate
    From    TrialBalance As tb
    Where   tb.RowNum = 1

    Union All

    Select   tb.RowNum
            ,rb.memberid
            ,Cast((rb.deposit + tb.deposit - tb.withdrawal) As Decimal(18,2)) 
            ,rb.withdrawal
            ,tb.trdate
    From    TrialBalance As tb
            Join RunningBalance As rb On tb.RowNum = (rb.Rownum + 1) And tb.memberid = rb.memberid
)

Select   rb.memberid
        ,Min(rb.deposit) As runningBalance
From    RunningBalance As rb
Where   Year(rb.trdate) = 2015
        And Month(rb.trdate) = 1
Group By rb.memberid
```

Comment: ok, don't worry, everyone are here to help each other. let us know any further query

Comment: I've been wondering what is the use of 'Set Nocount On'. Is that use to improve the performance in your insert only?

Comment: Kindly visit below link
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1226/set-nocount-on-improves-sql-server-stored-procedure-performance/

Comment: sorry for the long time to reply. base on the above example it is working but not tested on my actual table with almost 500k records. I still cannot fully grasp how the code worked. There is still part of the code that i cannot understand so I'm trying to read some concepts on how this worked. I need to join the output of this table to a another manually created table.  i don't want to implement something I cannot understand. For troubleshooting purposes.  Thanks for the idea i hope I can work it out

Comment: I've been testing this code and the performance does takes its toll. It's slower than what I'm producing using C# but this code  gave me an idea how to make it using sql. hopefully i can post my revision. I'm still doing some test.

Comment: May i know which version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: I'm testing this on sql server 2005 and 2008 as we have 2 servers. As what I understand on the code is it loops ALL members running balance from the beginning of savings until the end of all the member record which makes the code takes time. Then will be filtered by specified month.

Comment: my revision to improve the performance is to get the sum of all withdrawal and deposit from beginning till BEFORE 1st day of the specified month.Then get the loop of the running balance from of the specified month (Reducing the loop). then Add the total of sum from the beginning till specified month to the running balance. Then I Filter the lowest value in the loop using min. formula(sum of beginning to before 01/01/2015) + (value of the running balance of the specified month from 01/01/2015 to 01/31/2015). This reduces the no of loop. still testing my code.I got the idea from your code Thanks

Comment: I like that, you have not completely depend on any given code and instead you tried your own. This way you will learn so much. And if you going this way, that is sure, you will love SQL Server more than other tech.

Comment: Sorry, i have not able to give much time, but I read your comment and as you say, 'filtered by month', then I think 'if you are looking for specific month then that filter should be applied first so the amount of data on which you need to work will be less.

Comment: I loved sql ever since someone taught me here on stackoverflow how to compute using sql only(server side computation). It reduced my multiple queries into 1querry. well in fact almost all my query in my program is only 1 query but there are still i cannot do such like this and the learning curve is so exciting. I am very thankful to the community like you who gives answers and ideas how to do it. I will post my code after i've proven that it generates the correct and necessary output.